CI/CD Pipelines with AWS SAM
I've been building and deploying my stack manually during development using sam build and sam deploy, and understand how that  and the samconfig.toml work. But now I'm trying to get a CI/CD pipeline in place since we're ready to go to the other environments and ultimately deploy to prod. I feel like I understand most of what I need, but am falling a little short when putting some parts together.
My previous team had a pipeline in place, but it was made years ago and didn't leverage SAM commands. DevOps had created a similar pipeline for me using Terraform, but I'm running into some issues with it. The other teams didn't use images for Lambdas, which my current team is doing now, so I think some things need to be done slightly different so that the ECR repo is created and associated properly. I have some freedom to create my own pipeline if needed, so I'm taking a stab at it.
Here is some information about my use case:

We have three AWS accounts for each environment. (dev, staging, prod)
My template.yaml is built to work in all environments through the use of parameters and pseudo parameters.
An existing CodeStar connection exists already in each account, so I figure I can reuse that ARN.
We have branches for dev, staging, and master. I would like a process where we merge a branch into dev, and the dev AWS account runs the pipeline to deploy everything. And then the same for staging/staging and master/prod.
I'm using CodePipeline and GitHub.

I've been following the docs and articles on how to get a pipeline set up, but some things aren't 100% clear to me. I'm following the process of sam pipeline bootstrap and sam pipeline init. Here is what I understand so far (please correct me if I'm wrong):

sam pipeline bootstrap creates the necessary resources in the AWS account for the pipeline. The generated ARNs are stored in a config file so that they can be referenced later when creating the template for the pipeline resources and deploying the pipeline. I have to do this for each stage, and each stage in my case would be dev, staging, and prod, which are all separate AWS accounts.
I used the built-in two-stage template when running sam pipeline init, but I need three stages. Looking over the generated template, I think I should be able to alter it to support all three stages that I need.

I haven't deployed the pipeline template yet, as this is where I start to get confused. This built-in template is mainly referencing a feature branch vs a main branch (their 2-stages). In my case, I don't necessarily care about various feature branches out there, but rather only care about the three specific branches for each environment. Has anyone used this template and run into a similar use case to me?
And then the other thing I'm wondering about is when it comes to version control. There are several files generated for this pipeline. Am I meant to check-in all of these files (aside from files in .aws-sam) into the repo? It seems like if I wanted to modify or redeploy the pipeline, I would want this codepipeline.yaml and pipeline folder. But the template has many of the ARNs hardcoded. Is that seen as an issue? Or should I move all that into something like a secret in Secrets Manager? That's where we usually keep our parameters for these SAM templates.

So basically, as you know one pipeline has two stages (I suppose you are using AWS Quick Start Pipeline Templates), dev and prod. Based on that, what you can do is to create two pipelines (now you have 4 stages), and have one of the stage removed. There are some manual processes involved.
Steps:

Type sam pipeline init --bootstrap, and give the first two stages the settings you want. For instance, you can name them dev-app and stg-app. If it went smooth, you should be able to see .aws-sam/pipeline/pipelineconfig.toml in your project directory.
Rename the autogenerated template.yaml as template_one.yaml.
Move the pipeline/pipelineconfig.toml to somewhere else outside of the .aws-sam for now (you will need it later). This step is necessary because as long as pipeline/pipelineconfig.toml is in place under .aws-sam , you won't be able to create another pipeline.
Run sam pipeline init --bootstrap in your project directory again, and name the two stages, prod-app and prod-app-two.
After step 4, you should be able to see another pipeline/pipelineconfig.toml with a different pipeline_user ARN.
Now, you can move the config parameters for prod-appfrom the 2nd pipelineconfig.toml into the 1st pipelineconfig.toml(which you moved to somewhere else earlier), and delete the 2nd .toml file and move the first 1st .toml file back under .aws-sam/pipeline. This is to make sure the three stages, dev-app, stg-app and prod-app have the same pipeline user.
Keep in mind, you might have to manually delete the s3 buckets created for prod-app-two, which is redundant now.

Now you should also have 2 yaml files, one is template_one.yaml and the other one is template.yaml, you can merge the two files into one and in the final template.yaml file you can set up the configs like which stage is for which branch.
This is my approach. I know it is a little bit complicated. I ran into this puzzle earlier this year. I spent a lot of time on looking up things like which file does what, and I came up this work around solution in my head without running it first. And then I built a sample project using this approach, and it worked.
